# Javascript object array to string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Assuming I have an object array:

```
array=[
  {
    "Item": "A"
    "Quantity" : 2
  },
  {
    "Item": "B"
    "Quantity" : 7
  },
  {
    "Item": "C"
    "Quantity" : 1
  }
]
```

I am wondering what would be my options to get the following string output :

```
(A, 2), (B, 7), (C,1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the most elegant way to do this but it's easy to understand:

```
array = [{
    "Item": "A",
    "Quantity": 2
  },
  {
    "Item": "B",
    "Quantity": 7
  },
  {
    "Item": "C",
    "Quantity": 1
  }
];

var str = "";
for (var a = 0; a < array.length; a++) {
  str += "(";
  str += array[a].Item + ",";
  str += array[a].Quantity + ")";
  if (a != array.length - 1) {
    str += ",";
  }
}
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could `map` the [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and `join` like this:

- Loop through the array using `map`
- `Object.values(a)` returns an array like this: `["A", 2]`
- `join` them using and wrap a `()` around using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- join the resulting string array from `map` using another `join`

```js
const array = [
  {
    "Item": "A",
    "Quantity" : 2
  },
  {
    "Item": "B",
    "Quantity" : 7
  },
  {
    "Item": "C",
    "Quantity" : 1
  }
]

const str = array.map(a => `(${ Object.values(a).join(", ") })`)
                 .join(", ")
                 
console.log(str)
```

If you're okay with `(A,2), (B,7), (C,1)` without a space in between them,
you could simply use

```js
const array=[{"Item":"A","Quantity":2},{"Item":"B","Quantity":7},{"Item":"C","Quantity":1}]

const str = array.map(a => `(${ Object.values(a) })`).join(", ")
console.log(str)
```

Comment: you need ordered objects and not more properties for this approach.

Comment: @NinaScholz You're right. I'm assuming OP has provided MCVE and created the objects in the way it's mentioned in the question :)

Answer (score 1):

You could map the values and join them.

```js
var array = [{ Item: "A", Quantity: 2 }, { Item: "B", Quantity: 7 }, { Item: "C", Quantity: 1 }],
    string = array
        .map(({ Item, Quantity }) => `(${[Item, Quantity].join(', ')})`)
        .join(', ');
    
console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`array.map(function(item){ return "(" + item.Item + "," + item.Quantity + ")"}).join(",");`

```js
var array=[
  {
    "Item": "A",
    "Quantity" : 2
  },
  {
    "Item": "B",
    "Quantity" : 7
  },
  {
    "Item": "C",
    "Quantity" : 1
  }
];
var result = array.map(function(item){ return "(" + item.Item + "," + item.Quantity + ")"}).join(",");
console.log(result);
```